# Can I control airplane mode or wireless/data connection on a USB-connected Android phone?

Tags: windows, macos, drivers, android

Is it possible to control or monitor

- airplane mode
- WiFi
- Data/3G connection

of an Android phone (e.g. Samsung Galaxy or OnePlus One) running CyanogenMod, from a Windows PC or a Mac?

I want to connect the android phone to my computer and monitor it from there using a driver.

Comment: Probably, but you need to be more specific about "the phone"?

Comment: Just a regular android phone such as Samsung Galaxy, or the OnePLus One (http://oneplus.net/de/one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using the [Android debugging bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html), for example for WiFi and 3G/data:

```
adb shell svc wifi enable
adb shell svc wifi disable

adb shell svc data enable
adb shell svc data disable
```

Other services can be enabled/disabled. Look at the list using:

```
adb shell service list
```

To [toggle Airplane mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506591/turning-airplane-mode-on-via-adb):

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS & adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_ENTER & adb shell input keyevent 4
```

The phone obviously needs to have debugging enabled and you need to install `adb` with the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) (the SDK tools at the bottom of the page will be enough).

Answer (score 1):

For switching the *Airplane mode*, I would rather use the following than trying to manipulate the GUI programmatically.

To enable the *Airplane mode*:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

To disable the *Airplane mode*:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 0
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

As slhck wrote, you need [adb (Android Debugging Bridge)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) from the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).